# Converting Prefix to Postfix

Tags: java, stack

I am currently trying to create a program that converts a prefix expression to a postfix expression but am having a lot of trouble getting my stack to work as intended.

My goal is to create a reversal stack that will store the initial prefix expression, then pop the tokens one by one.

```
StringTokenizer defaultTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, " ", false);
    
    //First while loop to push tokens on reversal stack
    while (defaultTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String c = defaultTokenizer.nextToken();
        reversalStack.push(c + " ");
    }
```

**if the token is an operand:**

add them to an operand stack if they are operands

**else if the next token is an operator:**

pop two operands, add them into one string with the operator and then add them to the operand stack

```
//Second while loop that pops the reversal stack one at a time
    while (reversalStack.isEmpty() == false) {
        String c = reversalStack.pop(); 
        //if the token is an operand, add it to the operand stack
        if(!isOperator(c) == true){
            operandStack.push(c);
        //if the token is an operator, pop two operands, combine them with the operator
        //into one string and push them into the operand stack as one string
        }else{
            String op1 = operandStack.pop();
            String op2 = operandStack.pop();
            String temp = op1 + op2 + c;
            operandStack.push(temp);
        }
    }
    
    //Pop the postfix expression
    String result = operandStack.pop();
    return result;
}
```

The current Prefix expression I am testing this with is "* 2 + 2 - + 12 9 2" but I am only getting the multiplication sign given as an output. In case my issue lies somewhere else in my code, I have added the entire class below.

```
    import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

Public class Main {
static Stack<String> reversalStack = new Stack<String>();
static Stack<String> operandStack = new Stack<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "* 2 + 2 - + 12 9 2";
    
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(new Main().convert(test));
}

boolean isOperator(String x){
    switch (x){
        case "-":
        case "+":
        case "/":
        case "*":
        case "^":
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String convert(String expression) {

    StringTokenizer defaultTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, " ", false);
    
    //First while loop to push tokens on reversal stack
    while (defaultTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String c = defaultTokenizer.nextToken();
        reversalStack.push(c + " ");
    }
    
    //Second while loop that pops the reversal stack one at a time
    while (reversalStack.isEmpty() == false) {
        String c = reversalStack.pop(); 
        //if the token is an operand, add it to the operand stack
        if(!isOperator(c) == true){
            operandStack.push(c);
        //if the token is an operator, pop two operands, combine them with the operator
        //into one string and push them into the operand stack as one string
        }else{
            String op1 = operandStack.pop();
            String op2 = operandStack.pop();
            String temp = op1 + op2 + c;
            operandStack.push(temp);
        }
    }
    
    //Pop the postfix expression
    String result = operandStack.pop();
    return result;
}
```

}

Sorry for the formatting errors, I am having issues copy pasting my code over. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're overthinking this. Pop your prefix stack and push whatever it is into the postfix stack. Rinse and repeat while the prefix stack is non-empty. "Add them into one string with the operator" is completely wrong, and so is having two stacks. Or just call `reverse()`, wherever it is (`Collections`?).

Answer (score 0):

You get just one operand item because you pop only one of them from the operand stack as a return value:

```java
String result = operandStack.pop();
return result;
```

[Stack.pop() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop--):

> public E pop(): Removes **the object at the top** of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function.